# Android Studio - Cannot select module from Edit Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I just checked out my project onto another system from GitHub. I have searched and could not find a solution. I have already tried to remake project and sync project with gradle files. This is my problem. When I press play (the green arrow), the 'Edit configuration' window pops up:

[image]

In the drop-down list for 'Module', there are no modules.
To try and check/fix this, I right clicked on my project, went to Module Settings, which brought up this window, and my Module seems to be registered here. So what is the problem? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: could you show us your grade module?

Comment: build.grade (Module: ****)

Comment: having the same issue. Where to find the build.grade(Module: ****)? Is it something like this? --> com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0